# Como detectar si unas palabras juntas están incluidas en un texto python

Tags: python

No encuentro como resolver mi duda, necesito detectar si unas palabras juntas están incluidas en un texto

comprendo que si quiero buscar una palabra haría algo como esto:

```
palabras in texto:
  print("incluida")
#Esto sería para una palabra lo que ami me gustaría encontrar algo como esto aceptando que tiene esas palabras en el texto:

 palabras= ["hola mundo" , " hola mundo" , "hola mundo "]
 texto = "Aprendiendo a escribir hola mundo en python"``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Silvio!
La manera como te encuentras intentando resolver el problema tiene un inconveniente, y es que `palabras in texto` busca si cada palabra incluida en `palabras` se encuentra contenido en `texto`. El problema con este método es que solo funcionaría si buscas una sola palabra en tu oración, ya que el ciclo for va iterando sobre cada palabra de `palabras`.

Para este problema puedes hacer una búsqueda mediante expresiones regulares de esta manera:

```py
import re

texto = 'Aprendiendo a escribir hola mundo en python'
palabras = ["hola mundo", " hola mundo", "hola mundo "]

for palabra in palabras:
    if re.search(r'\b' + palabra.lower() + r'\b', texto.lower()):
        print('Incluida')
    else:
        print('No incluida')
```

El ciclo for se encarga de recorrer cada palabra de `palabras`, verificando con el método `re.search()` el primer lugar donde el patrón de la expresión regular produce una coincidencia (Siendo el patrón introducido cada `palabra` en medio de `\b \b`, indicando que estamos buscando esa palabra independiente), retornando así si una palabra se encuentra incluida o no.